# jQuery conflicting with prototype in Magento

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, prototypejs

I have this jQuery in a Magento install:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    "use strict";
    var firstItems = $('.item.first');
    // Find tallest .item per row; match rest of row to it
    firstItems.each(function($) {
        var $first, row, headings, heights, maxHeight;
        $first = $(this);
        row = $first.add($first.nextUntil(firstItems));
        headings = row.find("h2, h5");
        heights = headings.map(function($) {
            return $(this).outerHeight();
        });
        maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, heights);
        headings.css("height", maxHeight);
    });
});
```

Sadly, it's conflicting with Prototype. It is throwing the error:

```
[object object] is not a valid argument for 'Function.prototype.apply'
```

This leads me to believe that the conflict is coming from line 15:

```
maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, heights);
```

Is there any way that I can wrap that function differently so that it's ignored by prototype?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are [`.applying`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) a jQuery object, where as it should be an array.

```
    heights = headings.map(function($) {
        return $(this).outerHeight();
    }).toArray(); //<-- convert to array
```

Prototype the library doesn't add `Function.prototype.apply`, it's a native method.

Comment: This is a *fantastic* answer! You explained more about how JS works, which helps me (and other viewers) learn. I am not accepting quick fix answers like "just use jQuery.noConflict();".

Comment: @JezenThomas that wouldn't help anyway since you are using locally scoped `$` and you will not see errors like this from jQuery conflicts. See https://www.google.com/?q=%22is+not+a+valid+argument+for%22+%22Function.prototype.apply%22 If you don't want to take my word for it ;P

Comment: @JezenThomas, the "quick fix answer" was not an answer at all. you are already using one of the good techniques (locally scoped as mentioned by @Esailija) -- `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {});` That doesn't require the use of `jQuery.noConflict()`. You are passing the `$` as parameter to the function, which means you are using a local variable `$` as the 1st parameter - which is always `jQuery`. You can check this using `arguments[0]` in `function() {}`. Anyways, your problem was different than `noConflict` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
 jQuery(function($){
      code_with_$;
 });
```

and

```
(function($){
    code_with_$;
})(jQuery);
```

also you required to declare jQuery above prototype. (You can use page.xml to define position of jQuery above prototype.)Then use your jQuery code using above mentioned structure it will resolve your problem.